# preg match monetary patterns

Tags: php, preg-match

https://regex101.com/r/3e0fbp/2

I have some patterns to match monetary amounts, but some of the patterns doesn't work 100%

**haystack**

```
1.000,39-
1.000,39
39,9
45,4-
22.323.222,49
40
58-
333.294
33.292,00%
33.292,00 %
39 %
22%
-22,29
-4.343,1
```

**match amounts with 2 decimals (DO NOT match percentages)**

```
(?<![\d.,])-?\d{1,3}(?:[,. ]?\d{3})*[.,]\d{2}-?(?![\d.,%]|(?: %))
```

This pattern works!

**match amounts with 0-2 decimals (DO NOT match percentages)**

```
(?<![\d.,])-?\d{1,3}(?:[,. ]?\d{3})*(?:[^.,]|[.,]\d{1,2})-?(?![\d.,%]|(?: %))
```

This pattern doesn't work. Matches `20%`

**match amounts with 1-2 decimals (DO NOT match percentages)**

```
(?<![\d.,])-?\d{1,3}(?:[,. ]?\d{3})*[.,]\d{1,2}-?(?![\d.,%]|(?: %))
```

This pattern works!

**match amounts with 2 decimals (may match percentages)**

```
(?<![\d.,])-?\d{1,3}(?:[,. ]?\d{3})*[.,]\d{2}-?(?![\d.,])
```

This pattern works!

**match amounts with 0-2 decimals (may match percentages)**

```
(?<![\d.,])-?\d{1,3}(?:[,. ]?\d{3})*(?:[^.,]|[.,]\d{1,2})-?(?![\d.,])
```

This pattern doesn't work. Doesn't match `333.294`

**match amounts with 1-2 decimals (may match percentages)**

```
(?<![\d.,])-?\d{1,3}(?:[,. ]?\d{3})*[.,]\d{1,2}-?(?![\d.,])
```

This pattern works!

**code**

```
function get_number_pattern(int $decimals_min=2, int $decimals_max=2, bool $allow_percentage=false): string{
    $pattern = '(?<![\d.,])-?\d{1,3}(?:[,. ]?\d{3})*';

    if($decimals_min || $decimals_max){
        if($decimals_min == $decimals_max){
            $decimal_num = $decimals_min;
        }
        else{
            $decimal_num = ($decimals_min ?: '1').','.$decimals_max;
        }

        $decimals = '[.,]\d{'.$decimal_num.'}';
        if($decimals_min){
            $pattern .= $decimals.'-?';
        }
        else{
            $pattern .= '(?:[^.,]|'.$decimals.')-?';
        }
    }

    $negative_trailing = [
        '[\d'.($decimals ? '.,' : '').($allow_percentage ? '' : '%').']'
    ];

    if(!$allow_percentage){
        $negative_trailing[] = '(?: %)';
    }

    $pattern .= '(?!'.implode('|', $negative_trailing).')';

    return $pattern;
}

echo get_number_pattern()."\n";
echo get_number_pattern(0, 2)."\n";
echo get_number_pattern(1, 2)."\n";

echo get_number_pattern(2, 2, true)."\n";
echo get_number_pattern(0, 2, true)."\n";
echo get_number_pattern(1, 2, true)."\n";
```

Comment: That formatting doesn't look nice..

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: For the problem not really since I don't know regex. For the question formatting, I'd at least replace `#` (heading) with just `**..**` (regular bold). I also got confused when I read `this pattern works` - as I didn't know if it was the previous or the following, but attention solved it xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this for your first problem (here you missed the `%` in your group after the first digits):

```
(?<![\d.,])-?\d{1,3}(?:[,. ]?\d{3})*(?:[^.,%]|[.,]\d{1,2})-?(?![\d.,%]|(?: %))
```

and this for second one (here you missed the `%` at the end and the space):

```
(?<![\d.,])-?\d{1,3}(?:[,. ]?\d{3})*(?:[^.,]|[.,]\d{1,2})-?(?![\d.,])(?: ?%)?
```